# How to fix calico.yaml for kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

Trying several options to resolve the issue with weave-net ([How to fix weave-net CrashLoopBackOff for the second node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872332/how-to-fix-weave-net-crashloopbackoff-for-the-second-node)), I have decided to try calico instead of weave-net. The documentation for kubernetes tells I need only one or another. The command (as per documentation here https://github.com/projectcalico/calico-containers/tree/master/docs/cni/kubernetes/manifests/kubeadm) fails:

```
vagrant@vm-master:~$ sudo kubectl create -f https://github.com/projectcalico/calico-containers/blob/master/docs/cni/kubernetes/manifests/kubeadm/calico.yaml
yaml: line 6: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

**What I am doing wrong? Is it known issue? How can I fix/workaround it?**

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the raw YAML file in your command, instead of the full GitHub HTML document:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico-containers/master/docs/cni/kubernetes/manifests/kubeadm/calico.yaml
```

Comment: Ohh.. sure, got it... how could I miss it :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your HTML URL with raw data URL, it will work.